# how to get total no of scenarios from feature file (JAVA+cucumber)

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am using JAVA + cucumber for my automation . I would like to get total no of scenario's from my feature file in java code. I can only able to see No of feature file and total no of scenario's only after the run in HTML output file.Yes,i can count using **Scenario.getId()** in After method , but what if my test breakouts during run .

Also is there way to get total time taken for running the cucumber test in java .

Comment: Use the dryRun = true in cucumberoptions in your runner. This will give you the total number of scenarios, steps etc without actually running the code.

Comment: I wanted to get the values in Java code like scenario.getId() provide the id of the  current scenario .